# Anchor tag to change bottom-border color on selection

Tags: javascript, html, css

On my website, the top navigation menu bar has three menu items. I wanted to make it easier for users to know on which page they are on, without looking at the URL. Which means, I would like to make Bottom-border color to appear on each Menu item once it get selected. And If I am redirecting to another menu item, bottom-border color should change to new menu item.

How can I achieve this?

```
a {
  transition: all .3s; }
a:active,
a:hover,
a:visited {
outline: 0;
text-decoration: none; }
.main.sub-nav dd a:hover:after, .main.sub-nav dd a.active:after{
 bottom: -9px;
 background: #00ff00;
 display: block;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
See also: [ask] and include a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: with js on load check the url, then add `Active` to the button, and remove `Active` from others

Comment: You would need to either have a server side language and add a current class to whichever link you want when a page is loaded, add that class manually if you are using flat html pages for each page, or use js and map the url to the link to add the class.   Any way you look at it, you need to figure out how to get the current page, map it to a link and then add a class depending on that mapping.  Once you have tried something along those lines, if you get stuck, come back with a more specific error

Comment: @j08691 I made the changes to my question. Please take a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try matching `window.location.pathname`

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
      if (window.location.pathname == '/page1.html') {
           var menuItem1 = document.querySelector('#menu-item-1');
           menuItem1.style.borderBottom = '1px solid red';
      }
      if (window.location.pathname == '/page2.html') {
          // and so on
      }
});
```

- [`window.location` Documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/location)
- [`window.location.pathname` Documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/pathname)
- [`document.querySelector()` Documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: Hi Tom, can I get the same functionality without the use of JavaScript? Like only with CSS?

Comment: well, you can't access the URL in CSS but if you are working with static html files, in your page1.html, give the class `active` or something similar to your first menu item and add corresponding styling in your CSS: `.active { border-bottom: 1px solid red }`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in an onclick function:

```
var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName('navTab'); //Get every nav element

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(tabs,function(tab){
    tab.style.borderBottom = "2px solid #000000";  // Set every element's border back to normal
  });

  document.getElementById("tab" + tabNumber).style.borderBottom = "2px solid red";  //Set the selected border to a different color
```

Working demo:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pPZWYy

Comment: This is working great, but I am not sure if I can implement this on an Anchor tag?

Comment: You can always wrap the anchor tag in a div tag.